# How to make nodejs to talk with golang

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, go

I am creating a web app in node.js and golang. I need to connect nodejs with golang code which talks to mongodb and returns data to node program. is there any way to connect so? I tried to use gonode API.This is my code using gonode API.

my node.js file contains below code:

```
var Go = require('gonode').Go;
var options = {
path : 'gofile.go',
initAtOnce : true,
}

var go = new Go(options,function(err){
if(err) throw err;

go.execute({commandText: 'Hello world from gonode!'}, function(result, response) {
        if(result.ok) {
            console.log('Go responded: ' + response.responseText);
        }
});

go.close();
});     `
```

And this is the code in my gofile.go file:

```
package main

import(
    gonode "github.com/jgranstrom/gonodepkg"
    json "github.com/jgranstrom/go-simplejson"
)

func main(){
    gonode.Start(process)
}

func process(cmd *json.Json) (response *json.Json) {    
    response, m := json.MakeMap()

    if(cmd.Get("commandText").MustString() == "Hello") {
        m["responseText"] = "Well hello there!"
    } else {
        m["responseText"] = "What?"
    }

    return
}
```

This is the error am getting while running as node node.js in terminal

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:721:19)
```

Answer (score 8):

Golang from 1.5, you can build go to shared object binary file (*.so). This allows you to connect your go compiled library to be called by nodejs, python, ruby, java etc.

Here is a guide you could refer to: https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf

Answer (score 5):

thanks for the response. I got a solution for this. I made 2 different servers. One for NodeJS and another for Golang. I am calling golang uri in Node server and getting data from golang server.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a very cursive check of the gonode source code, the module seems to spawn go code as a child process and communicate through stdin/-out. EPIPE error means that the other end closed the stream. Based on this it might be that your go process exits prematurely.

You could try to debug the problem by modifying Command.prototype.execute in gonode/lib/command.js to print out the JSON that's sent to the go process. Then you can debug the go program by running it directly and giving it the same input via stdin.

Comment: Also, the go code example seems to work differently from your code. In the beginning of the function it calls response = make(gonode.CommandData) and in the if-statement the response is assigned like so: response["text"] = "What?". Don't know much about go, but it seems like your variable m isn't really linked to anything. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gonode